# Plotting pressure as a function of altitude

Tags: plotting

[image]

How can I make the plot shown above? It gives pressure as a function of altitude according to the barometric formula.

Comment: Meet us halfway. Can you give us the equation representing the barometric formula?

Comment: @J.M. Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula

Comment: @Mariusz, I know perfectly well what the barometric formula looks like, being a chemist. :) I was giving the OP a chance to improve his question by including the formula. In its current form I was sorely tempted to close it, but I decided to be nice.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. In order to learn how to use this site [take the tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). Users will appreciate you typing in your equations using  formatted inline code. [See the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) on how to do this.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardAtmosphereData.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different [equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) for computing pressure at various height regimes below **86 km**.

**The first equation is used when the value of standard temperature lapse rate is not equal to zero.**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Pb0 = 101325  (*Pa*);
Pb1 = 22632.1 (*Pa*);
Pb2 = 5474.89 (*Pa*);
Pb3 = 868.02  (*Pa*);
Pb4 = 110.91  (*Pa*);
Pb5 = 66.94   (*Pa*);
Pb6 = 3.96    (*Pa*);
Tb0 = 288.15  (*K*);
Tb1 = 216.65  (*K*);
Tb2 = 216.65  (*K*);
Tb3 = 228.65  (*K*);
Tb4 = 270.65  (*K*);
Tb5 = 270.65  (*K*);
Tb6 = 214.15  (*K*);
g0 = 9.860665 (*m/s^2*);
M = 0.0289644 (*kg/mol*);
hb0 = 0       (*m*);
hb1 = 11000   (*m*);
hb2 = 20000   (*m*);
hb3 = 32000   (*m*);
hb4 = 47000   (*m*);
hb5 = 51000   (*m*);
hb6 = 71000   (*m*);
R = 8.3144598 (* J/mol/K*);
Lb0 = -0.0065 (*k/m*);
Lb1 = 10^-9   (*k/m. I must put a small value not a Zero *);
Lb2 = 0.001   (*k/m*);
Lb3 = 0.0028  (*k/m*);
Lb4 = 10^-9   (*k/m. I must put a small value not a Zero *);
Lb5 = -0.0028 (*k/m*);
Lb6 = -0.002  (*k/m*);

P0[h_] := Pb0*(Tb0/(Tb0 + Lb0*(h - hb0)))^((g0*M)/(R*Lb0));
P1[h_] := Pb1*(Tb1/(Tb1 + Lb1*(h - hb1)))^((g0*M)/(R*Lb1));
P2[h_] := Pb2*(Tb2/(Tb2 + Lb2*(h - hb2)))^((g0*M)/(R*Lb2));
P3[h_] := Pb3*(Tb3/(Tb3 + Lb3*(h - hb3)))^((g0*M)/(R*Lb3));
P4[h_] := Pb4*(Tb4/(Tb4 + Lb4*(h - hb4)))^((g0*M)/(R*Lb4));
P5[h_] := Pb5*(Tb5/(Tb5 + Lb5*(h - hb5)))^((g0*M)/(R*Lb5));
P6[h_] := Pb6*(Tb6/(Tb6 + Lb6*(h - hb6)))^((g0*M)/(R*Lb6));

PP[h_] :=  Piecewise[{{P0[h], h <= 11000}, {P1[h], 11000 <= h <= 20000}, {P2[h],
20000 <= h <= 32000}, {P3[h], 32000 <= h <= 47000}, {P4[h], 
47000 <= h <= 51000}, {P5[h], 51000 <= h <= 71000}, {P6[h], 71000 <= h <= 86000}}]

Plot[Labeled[{PP[h]}, "Pressure as a function of the height above the sea level", 
9000], {h, 0, 71000}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red,AxesLabel -> {"h[m]", "P[Pa]"}]
Plot[Labeled[{PP[h]}, "Pressure as a function of the height above the sea level", 
100], {h, 0, 86000}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"h[m]", "P[Pa]"}]

Plot[Labeled[{PP[h]/100}, "Pressure as a function of the height above the sea level", 
5000], {h, 0, 21000}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1013.25}}, 
PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"h[km]", "P[hPa]"}, 
Ticks -> {Table[{1000 i, i}, {i, 1, 21, 2}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

**I'm used the second equation is used when standard temperature lapse rate equals zero.**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Pb0 = 101325  (*Pa*);
Pb1 = 22632.10(*Pa*);
Pb2 = 5474.89 (*Pa*);
Pb3 = 868.02  (*Pa*);
Pb4 = 110.91  (*Pa*);
Pb5 = 66.94   (*Pa*);
Pb6 = 3.96    (*Pa*);
Tb0 = 288.15  (*K*);
Tb1 = 216.65  (*K*);
Tb2 = 216.65  (*K*);
Tb3 = 228.65  (*K*);
Tb4 = 270.65  (*K*);
Tb5 = 270.65  (*K*);
Tb6 = 214.15  (*K*);
g0 = 9.860665 (*m/s^2*);
M = 0.0289644 (*kg/mol*);
hb0 = 0       (*m*);
hb1 = 11000   (*m*);
hb2 = 20000   (*m*);
hb3 = 32000   (*m*);
hb4 = 47000   (*m*);
hb5 = 51000   (*m*);
hb6 = 71000   (*m*);
R = 8.3144598 (*J/mol/K*);

P0[h_] := Pb0*Exp[-g0*M*(h - hb0)/(R*Tb0)];
P1[h_] := Pb1*Exp[-g0*M*(h - hb1)/(R*Tb1)];
P2[h_] := Pb2*Exp[-g0*M*(h - hb2)/(R*Tb2)];
P3[h_] := Pb3*Exp[-g0*M*(h - hb3)/(R*Tb3)];
P4[h_] := Pb4*Exp[-g0*M*(h - hb4)/(R*Tb4)];
P5[h_] := Pb5*Exp[-g0*M*(h - hb5)/(R*Tb5)];
P6[h_] := Pb6*Exp[-g0*M*(h - hb6)/(R*Tb6)];

PP[h_] := Piecewise[{{P0[h], h <= 11000}, {P1[h], 11000 <= h <= 20000}, {P2[h],
 20000 <= h <= 32000}, {P3[h], 32000 <= h <= 47000}, {P4[h], 
 47000 <= h <= 51000}, {P5[h], 51000 <= h <= 71000}, {P6[h], 71000 <= h <= 86000}}]

 Plot[Labeled[{PP[h]}, "Pressure as a function of the height above the sea level", 
 5000], {h, 0, 51000}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"h[m]", "P[Pa]"}]

 Plot[Labeled[{PP[h]/100}, "Pressure as a function of the height above the sea level", 
 4000], {h, 0, 21000}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1013.25}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"h[km]", "P[hPa]"}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{1000 i, i}, {i, 1, 21, 2}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

**We can use  equations from** [Practical Meteorology](https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/books/Practical_Meteorology/prmet/PracticalMet_WholeBook-v1_00b.pdf)

```
p1 = 1013.258*(288.15/(288.15 - 6.5*h))^(-5.255877);(* hPa *)
p2 = 226.32*Exp[-0.1577*(h - 11)];
p3 = 54.749*(216.65/(216.65 + 1*(h - 20)))^34.16319;
p4 = 8.868*(228.65/(228.65 + 2.8*(h - 32)))^12.2011;
p5 = 1.1109*Exp[-0.1262*(h - 47)];
P[h_] := Piecewise[{{p1, h <= 11}, {p2, 11 <= h <= 20}, {p3, 
20 <= h <= 32}, {p4, 32 <= h <= 47}, {p5, 47 <= h <= 51}}]
Plot[Labeled[P[h], "Pressure as a function of the height above the sea level", 8], {h, 
0, 51}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {h, P}]
```

[image]

**EDITED: 15.10.2017.**

**[U.S. Standard Atmosphere-1976 year](http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmmodel.htm) from 0 to 1000 km.**

```
p1 = 1013.25*(288.15/(288.15 - 6.5*h))^(-5.255877);
p2 = 226.32*Exp[-0.1577*(h - 11)];
p3 = 54.749*(216.65/(216.65 + 1*(h - 20)))^34.16319;
p4 = 8.868*(228.65/(228.65 + 2.8*(h - 32)))^12.2011;
p5 = 1.1109*Exp[-0.1262*(h - 47)];
p6 = 0.6693887*(270.65/(270.65 - 2.8*(h - 51)))^-12.2011;
p7 = 0.03956420*(214.65/(214.65 - 2*(h - 71)))^-17.0816;
p8 = Exp[2.159582*10^-6*h^3 - 4.836957*10^-4*h^2 - 0.1425192*h + 13.47530];
p9 = Exp[3.304895*10^-5*h^3 - 0.00906273*h^2 + 0.6516698*h - 11.03037];
p10 = Exp[6.693926*10^-5*h^3 - 0.01945388*h^2 + 1.71908*h - 47.75030];
p11 = Exp[-6.539316*10^-5*h^3 + 0.02485568*h^2 - 3.223620*h + 
135.9355];
p12 = Exp[2.283506*10^-7*h^4 - 1.343221*10^-4*h^3 + 0.02999016*h^2 - 
3.055446*h + 113.5764];
p13 = Exp[1.20943*10^-8*h^4 - 9.692458*10^-6*h^3 + 0.003002041*h^2 - 
0.4523015*h + 19.19151];
p14 = Exp[8.113942*10^-10*h^4 - 9.822568*10^-7*h^3 + 4.687616*10^-4*h^2 - 
0.1231710*h + 3.067409];
p15 = Exp[9.814674*10^-11*h^4 - 1.654439*10^-7*h^3 + 1.148115*10^-4*h^2 - 
0.05431334*h - 2.011365];
p16 = Exp[-7.835161*10^-11*h^4 + 1.96489*10^-7*h^3 - 
1.657213*10^-4*h^2 + 0.04305869*h - 14.77132];
p17 = Exp[2.813255*10^-11*h^4 - 1.120689*10^-7*h^3 + 1.695568*10^-4*h^2 - 
0.1188941*h + 14.56718];

P2[h_] := Piecewise[{{p1, h <= 11}, {p2, 11 <= h <= 20}, {p3, 
20 <= h <= 32}, {p4, 32 <= h <= 47}, {p5, 47 <= h <= 51}, {p6, 
51 <= h <= 71}, {p7, 71 <= h <= 86}, {p8, 86 <= h <= 91}, {p9, 
91 <= h <= 100}, {p10, 100 <= h <= 110}, {p11, 
110 <= h <= 120}, {p12, 120 <= h <= 150}, {p13, 
150 <= h <= 200}, {p14, 200 <= h <= 300}, {p15, 
300 <= h <= 500}, {p16, 500 <= h <= 750}, {p17, 750 <= h <= 1000}}]

Plot[Labeled[P2[h],"Pressure as a function of the height above the sea level", 
1.5], {h, 0, 1000}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"h[km]", "P[hPa]"}]
```

[image]

We can see discontinuity it is caused by two different models.